# Implementing an Algorithm in Hadoop and java

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop

Hi I am trying to implement a newly built bioinformatics algorithm in Hadoop and Java (I am not sure if it could be done). I have searched a lot over internet for implementing the algorithm on Hadoop. However all I find is "Identify the parallel tasks and execute them over hadoop". I would really appreciate if you guys can guide me to the right resources of Hadoop with Java over internet where I could find some solid example other than word count.
I know Java well, but hadoop is my first time. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I want to do

I have a very large text file (approx 100 MB) which have lines of characters (A,G,T,C) randomized.Long sequences of randomized A,G,T,C might form a string of important sequence k for eg (ATCGAGC). I might find this sequence k-mer in many lines of this text file called 'r'.

I have to perform following tasks

1. Identify the position of various k-mer in all lines of text(r) in R (whole set/file)
2. I have to keep track of positions of k-mer in a particular r.
3. I have two parameters which are used to compare the k-mers in various r.
4. If the k-mers in two 'r'  satisfy the above parameter comparison I have to update the neighbor set N

If you are interested this is the pseudo code  here it is

```
Given k, ĥ, ȇ
    1.  Make K  by extracting all possible kmers  from Reads
    2.  for all reads r belongs R do
            construct Gk[r] by scanning through r
            end for
    3.  for all k ε K do
                   for all read pairs (r,s) ε Gk × GK
                    if h(r,s) ≥ ĥ  and dk < ȇ h(r,s) then
                         update the N
                    end if
            end for
        end for

       k is k-mer
       K is set of all k
       ĥ minimum overlap distance
       ȇ maximum mismatch tolerance
       N neighbor set
       h(r,s)   overlap length of r and s wrt k
       d(r,s) distance between r and s
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this problem looks like 'set similarity' problem. There a bunch of them with various effectivity on mapreduce platforms. Start looking here http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html chapter3. But only if your primary task: learn hadoop. If not...

Second, 100MB - is a very small amount of data for hadoop. Definitely, you don't need hadoop at all. Even not more then 2 parallel tasks will be launched (by default hadoop launches 1 task per 64MB). You can implement any similarity algorithm in pure java, and it will works much faster.

Comment: Yes I agree with octo. Hadoop should be used when we have a large scale data in the order of greater than 10's of GB's.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is what I was looking for. Actually 100 mob is just a sample file. The real genome file can be huge.

Comment: Also, this is just a one out of three steps of algorithm. The algorithm generates 160 GB of data when applied on single node. That is the reason to implement on hadoop. Apologies for my naive question. And I really appreciate the solution. I think this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like finding for a pattern in the input file. Look at the [Grep.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/Grep.java) and the related files. It doesn't solve the exact problem in the OP, but is a closest match.